# Why does Point take less memory than Integer

Tags: java, memory

I'm measuring the sizes of objects by checking how long their byte arrays are using ByteArrayOutputStream.
When doing:

```
System.out.println(Utils.getObjectSize(new Integer(123123)));
System.out.println(Utils.getObjectSize(new Point(123, 123)));
```

They return 81 and 51.

I belive Point consists of two primitives but that doesn't seem to be the reason.

The code I for Utils.getObjectSize:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
objectStream.writeObject(object);
objectStream.close();
return byteStream.toByteArray().length;
```

**EDIT:**

I expressed myself wrong. I actually wanted to know why they take more size in the stream.

Comment: Can you please show, what is the result of System.out.println(Utils.getObjectSize(new Point(123123, 123123))); ?

Comment: The size of new Point(123123, 123123); is also 51

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start with the strings `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Number` and `value` appear in the serialization result for `Integer`. That should give a hint about why the serialization size is not very well correlated with the members of the object.

Here is some of the content of the resulting byte arrays listed: http://ideone.com/ragKZ

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.*;

class Test {

    public static byte[] getBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
        objectStream.writeObject(object);
        objectStream.close();
        return byteStream.toByteArray(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        byte[] iBytes = getBytes(new Integer(123123));
        System.out.println(new String(iBytes,  8, 17)); // "java.lang.Integer"
        System.out.println(new String(iBytes, 39,  5)); // "value"
        System.out.println(new String(iBytes, 48, 16)); // "java.lang.Number"
        // ...

        byte[] pBytes = getBytes(new Point(123, 123));
        System.out.println(new String(pBytes, 8, 14));  // "java.awt.Point"
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the same with `java.awt.Point` and `java.awt.Point2D`

Comment: Then sending an Integer over a stream seems like a bad idea? Should I always create a class holding the primitive integer for streams?

Comment: If you're that concerned with packing your data efficiently, I don't think using object streams are the recommended approach. Can't say I'm very experienced in this area though.

Comment: @Rob Fox, Alot of the inefficiency is not repeated per Object. Sending 10 Integer is not 10 times larger. However as @aioobe suggests, if you are worried about every byte, don't use plain Java serialization.  There are plenty of alternatives.

Comment: @Rob Fox - Are you looking for way to efficiently serialize classes with primitive values?

Comment: @ekeren I'm actually working on my second year java project and just ran into this and was wondering why it is so. I'm not that concerned with data efficiently right now but it would be interesting to know the alternatives (besides a primitive based protocol).

Comment: @Rob Fox: You might want to look at Protocol Buffers: http://protobuf.googlecode.com

Answer (score 7):

Your approach for finding the size of objects doesn't actually measure how much space they take up *in memory* at all.

`Point` will actually take *more* memory than `Integer` (for a 4-byte-aligned JVM; with 8 byte alignment they'll be the same) - it just happens to *serialize* to a smaller size, probably due to the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: If you have a JVM with an 8-byte boundary for allocation, they will be the same size. e.g. OpenJDK does this.

Answer (score 5):

Integer is larger to serialise because its parent `Number` is Serializable. If you print all the text bytes in the object serialisation you get

```
....sr..java.lang.Integer.......8...I..valuexr..java.lang.Number...........xp....
```

However, Point's parent is not Serializable and is not serialized.

```
....sr..java.awt.Point...r4~.&...I..xI..yxp...{...{
```

Also Integer's field name is longer (slightly)

```
byte[] bytes = byteStream.toByteArray();
for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++) {
    char ch = (char) bytes[i];
    if (ch >= ' ' && ch < 127)
        System.out.print(ch);
    else
        System.out.print('.');
}
System.out.println();
```

---

The method you are using looks at how large is the Object serialisation as a byte[], not how large it is in memory. The standard Java serialisation is not very efficient.

Integer is likely to consume 16 + 4 bytes and Point is likely to consume 16 + 2 * 4 bytes.  However as many JVMs allocate on a 8 byte boundary, you are likely to find they consume the same amount of memory.

The reason Integer is larger to serialize is that Java serializes not just the Object but its parents as well including listing what they are.

Comment: I investigated this issue and got the same result. I could not explain this better than you. Very good answer, Peter!

Answer (score 2):

You're measuring the size of the object when it's serialized to a stream. That won't be the same as the size of the object in memory.